# Basics: adding template tag to display custom fields in the post

Tags: custom-field

*I've just started learning so this might be a noob question*.

> Displaying Custom Fields
>
> With a Custom Field added to the post, it's time to display your books
>   and mood to the world. To display the Custom Fields for each post, use
>   the the_meta() template tag. The tag must be put within The Loop in
>   order to work. **Many people add the_meta() template tag to the end of
>   their post** or in their Post Meta Data Section.

<sup>- [Custom Fields on Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields)</sup>

I think I'm misinterpreting the bold part but I tried to add the tag `<?php the_meta(); ?>` in my post and it's not showing up.

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vREps.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should add `<?php the_meta(); ?>` in your `single.php` or in other relevant file.

reference [how to edit your theme files](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_Files#Using_the_Theme_Editor_and_Plugin_Editor)

Comment: Actually I'm going over with the rest of the tutorial, but I was just curious why **that** isn't working. Does it mean something else by "post" than what I understand?

Comment: you can't put the php code like that directly on content. unless you use a plugin of course. did you edit the file?